# Is it wise to access read-only data from multiple threads simultaneously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, readonly

I have an application that I'm trying to make multithreaded. Each thread will access a large chunk of read-only data.

Is is okay if multiple threads access the data simultaneously? I know that if the data were not read-only, I would need to use mutexes or some other form of synchronization to prevent race-conditions. But I'm wondering if it's okay to *read* the data without regard to synchronization.

The data in question will not be modified for the duration of **all** threads. The application will be running on Linux and Windows and is written in C++ if that makes any difference.

Comment: While the general answer is already given, I'd like to add a warning. Be careful if the resource is a database. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912489/read-only-access-only-for-sqlite3-from-multiple-threads

Comment: Maybe the critical issue is whether the performance will be affected even the read only is thread safe.  Say 100 threads are reading from a vector of 10000 elements from multiple random indexes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the data is read-only for the lifetime of all the threads that read it, then yes, it's perfectly fine to read without synchronization.

Comment: I think you beat me by 6 seconds

Comment: @Thomas: was about to post that on your answer :P

Comment: Lol :D I see what you guys did here!

Answer (score 14):

If the data is truly read-only for the duration of the multi-threaded access, then no synchronization is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's fine.

You shouldn't have any problem.

Answer (score 3):

If the data is fixed before any of the reading threads start, then yes, it's OK.