# Can two threads read same CONST block of memory at the same time

Tags: c, windows, linux, cpu, memory-access

Block of memory is initialized and set at the start of program and didn't change(CONST). For example:

static const int a = 10;

If it's dependent on the environment/architecture, then are these settings safe:

- Intel/AMD
- Win/Linux 32/64bits
- Thread per core or all threads at onecore.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643060/is-it-wise-to-access-read-only-data-from-multiple-threads-simultaneously

Comment: I was looking for this answer for 1 hour. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to read const for all architectures

Comment: Agreed, but a citation as to where this is specified would be nice.