# Read only access only for sqlite3 from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, thread-safety, system.data.sqlite

According to http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html there are three different threading modes when working with sqlite: *single-threaded*, *multi-threaded* and *serialized*. When configured to *serialized* and *multi-threaded* modes, mutexes are used (depending on the mode they are used more or less) and in *single-threaded* mode mutexes are not used at all.

Assuming that the database will only be used for queries (read-only access) is it possible to use the *single-threaded* mode while still accessing it from different threads? Or there are global resources that need to be protected?

In addition, can the default ADO.NET adapter [System.Data.Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) be used in the same manner?

Comment: I'd like to expand the question: I wonder if there is any performance difference between multi-threaded and serialized? If the access is read-only, they are equivalent, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQLite library has many internal data structures that get changed even for a read-only database file (caches, compiled statements, result sets, etc.), so you must *never* access a single-threaded connection from multiple threads.

ADO.NET does not make any thread safety guarantees, so [neither does System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/56.aspx).